# Use of textimage module

Tags: 7, media

how can we convert the contents of the article into image format using textimage module in drupal 7.

Suppose, we are viewing a article in some textformat (ie default format of drupal) and
if we want to see the contents of article in image format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Textimage 7.x-3.x

It provides a field formatter for long text. Be aware that very large text may create memory issues.

From README.TXT:

via Content Type field display formatters

- Access 'Content type' administration features via Administration->   Structure->Content Types
- Select the content type for which you want to manage a Textimage field   (e.g. Article, Basic page, etc.)
- If you need to create a new field, in the 'Manage Fields' tab, add a new   field of type 'Text' (or 'Long text', or 'Long text and summary') or   'Image'
- In the 'Manage Display' tab, select a 'Textimage' format for the field   created above (or any existing one)
- Click on the gear icon
- Select from the dropdown displayed the image style you want to use to   represent the content as a Textimage